# Update Info.plist values in archive

Tags: xcode, archive, info.plist

I need to be able to set a couple custom values in the Info.plist during the Xcode ARCHIVE process.  This is for Xcode 6 and Xcode 7.

I already have a script in place that successfully updates these values as a post-action on the BUILD process.  It works great when deploying to the simulator or to a phone from Xcode 6.

However, the Info.plist doesn't seem to be available from within the directory structures during the ARCHIVE process.  After a BUILD, I can find the results under .../Build/Products in $CONFIGURATION-iphoneos and $CONFIGURATION-iphonesimulator.  But after the ARCHIVE, there isn't anything there and I only find the compiled binaries under .../Build/Intermediates.

Certainly, I can see the Info.plist in the IPA itself.  Yet any attempts to update and replace this file after the fact are unsuccessful; the IPA is no longer valid, I assume due to checksum changes or something.

I don't want to update these values in the source Info.plist (e.g., using a pre-action) as it will always make the source dirty every time I archive.

Comment: Looking at how I might do a post-action on the Archive to actually update the archive itself before it is exported.  That seems promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  The process is nearly identical to the build -- use a post-action for the build, use a post-action for the archive -- just the path is different (all listed below) for where to find the Info.plist.

Below is my build script where I've used tokens for the "name" and the "value" to be updated in Info.plist.  I just copied this script and renamed it for use with the archive post-action.  Note that this script also has an example of extracting a value from Info.plist as I am deriving the web services version from the client version.

The path to the build Info.plist is either of:

```
"$BUILD_DIR/$CONFIGURATION-iphoneos/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Info.plist"
"$BUILD_DIR/$CONFIGURATION-iphonesimulator/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Info.plist"
```

NOTE: Both targets are being updated for a build since I've not figured out a way to identify which build it is doing.

The path to the archive Info.plist is:

```
"$ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH/Applications/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Info.plist"
```

Build post-action:

```
$SRCROOT/post_build.sh <value> ~/xcode_build_$PRODUCT_NAME.out
```

Build script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
# post_build.sh
#
# This script is intended for use by Xcode build process as a post-action.
# It expects the only argument is the value to be updated in Info.plist.  It
# derives the WS version for the URL from the version found in Info.plist.

printf "Running $0 using scheme '$SCHEME_NAME' as '$USER'\n"

# If this is a clean operation, just leave
if [ $COPY_PHASE_STRIP == "YES" ]
then
    printf "Doing a clean; exiting.\n"
    exit 1
fi

# Confirm that PlistBuddy is available
PLIST_BUDDY=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy
if ![-f "$PLIST_BUDDY"]
then
    printf "Unable to access $PLIST_BUDDY\n"
    exit 1
else
    printf "PLIST_BUDDY=$PLIST_BUDDY\n"
fi

# Function to perform the changes
updatePlist()
{
    PLIST_FILE=$1
    if [ -f "$PLIST_FILE" ]
    then
        printf "Determing WS version...\n"
        if [[ $SCHEME_NAME == *"Local"* ]]
        then
            WS_VER=""
        else
            # Determine the services version
            BUILD_VER=$(${PLIST_BUDDY} -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$PLIST_FILE")
            WS_VER=$(printf $BUILD_VER | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' | sed 's/\./_/g')
        fi

        # Update the plist
        ${PLIST_BUDDY} -c "Set <name> <value>" "$PLIST_FILE"
        printf "Updated plist $PLIST_FILE\n"
    else
        printf "Skipping -- no plist: $PLIST_FILE\n"
    fi
}

# Retrieve the supplied URL
BASE_URL=$1
printf "BASE_URL=$BASE_URL\n\n"

# Record the environment settings
printenv | sort > ~/xcode_build_$PRODUCT_NAME.env

# Locate the plist in the device build
printf "Checking device build...\n"
updatePlist "$BUILD_DIR/$CONFIGURATION-iphoneos/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Info.plist"
printf "\n"

# Locate the plist in the simulator build
printf "Checking simulator build...\n"
updatePlist "$BUILD_DIR/$CONFIGURATION-iphonesimulator/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Info.plist"
printf "\n"
```